# Cannot override function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I override function length in other file of js?

```
  jQuery(function ($) {    

    $.fn.normal_text = function (text) {
        
           $.fn.normal_text.length = function(){
              ...
           }
        
        }

}
```

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.normal_text.length = function(){ alert('123'); }
});
```

But it does not work. I seem to be crazy with it.

Comment: The property might have been sealed or frozen. Also can I point out that you are missing a semicolon at the end of that assignment.

Comment: I can not understand . Can you write clearly? Thanks

Comment: You should research Douglas Crockford's work on inheritance to get a better idea of how you should have done this. It's hard to answer a question like this correctly because it's unclear what you're intending to do.

Comment: Please, please tell me that you have your script tags the right way round and that jQuery actually exists before you are trying to do this. Do me a favour and just put `alert($ || "jQuery does not exist yet.");` into your code (not inside any functions, just at the top of your file.

Comment: Yes . It in the top file lib, and in my file js override too :)

Comment: Damn. I'm not too sure then without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override the `length` property on functions because it is a read-only builtin.

Under "Properties of function instances" in the language specification:

> ## [15.3.5.1 length](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.1)
>
> The value of the length property is an integer that indicates the “typical” number of arguments expected by the function. However, the language permits the function to be invoked with some other number of arguments. The behaviour of a function when invoked on a number of arguments other than the number specified by its length property depends on the function. This property has the attributes `{` **`[[Writable]]:` `false`**`,` `[[Enumerable]]:` `false,` `[[Configurable]]:` `false` `}`.

The bold part explains that the `length` property on function instances is not writable.

Comment: @Peter_175 this is what I was pointing out in my first comment.

Comment: So how can I change code before to edit function, can you show me

Comment: @RyanSmith, "might be sealed or frozen" is quite different from quoting the relevant portion of the spec.

Comment: @Peter_175, you can use a different property name.

Comment: Uhm, I change it temp to lengh_text but still not run to alert

Comment: @Peter_175, how are you calling it?  If `$.fn.normal_text` is called first, it will clobber your changes.

Comment: It in lib I call when run template layout. And in file view I include file js to override function $.fn.marsPortfolio.resizeFolio, and I place it in $(document).ready

Comment: @Peter_175, you should add a small, self-contained, runnable program to your question that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ryan Smith, Mike Samuel, namkha87 .Thank for helping, guys. 
Maybe in my code have problem. I should find out it myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

normal_text is a function, not an object so you can't override it's properties.